# How to make promise fail with an error in clojure?

Tags: asynchronous, clojure, promise

I am trying to learn about [Promise](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/promise) in clojure. From the docs, I can see we can create promise using **promise** function:

`(def p (promise))`

and we can resolve it using [deliver](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/deliver) function like this

`(deliver p 42)`

I want to understand, how can we reject a promise with error or exception. I've tried docs but it doesn't seems to help. I am new to functional programming and wondering there could be a different way for failed promises.

Comment: Can't you just deliver an object that represent an error? `(deliver p {:error "Couldn't connect", :other-info "Some info"})`. What behavior are you after?

Comment: That's what I ended up doing.  I was comparing clojure's promise with Javascript's promise where when you reject one, It invokes the `catch` block representing the error. but here the `promise result` is customized to represent an error or an exception

Comment: It's difficult to compare promises in the two languages. Javascript's is honestly more feature-rich. Clojure's promise is basically just a mutable container that can receive a value exactly once. If you look at its [source](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/841fa60b41bc74367fb16ec65d025ea5bde7a617/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L7016), it's really just a wrapper over an `atom` that includes some coordination.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **fail** function to reject a promise.

Please refer to [this](https://archive.clojure.org/design-wiki/display/design/Promises.html) link for more details.

Comment: While the design document you linked describes `fail`, it's not implemented in `clojure.core` as of version 1.10.1.

Comment: That's a proposal that hasn't been implemented yet. `fail` is supposedly a part of the `IDeliver` protocol, but that protocol doesn't exist yet.